# Pandas df.to_stata(): 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stata

Until now the pandas function `df.to_stata()` worked just fine with my datasets.

I am trying to export a dataframe that includes 29,778 rows and 37 to a Stata file using the following code:

```
df.to_stata("Stata_File.dta", write_index=False, version=118)
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I would really appreciate any help how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have multiple columns with the same column name by any chance?

Comment: Actually I did have columns with identical names. Renaming those solved the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Wouter could you please your comment as an answer? I'd like to close another one where i gave the same answer as yours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that this error arises when you have multiple columns with the same name in your dataframe